# OpenAPI generate nested object

Tags: java, spring, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a problem that happened when I tried to split my huge OpenAPI file into multiple files. I followed this [guide](https://davidgarcia.dev/posts/how-to-split-open-api-spec-into-multiple-files/). This is my `openapi.json` base file:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "Basic API",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/{mapName}/{animalId}/codes": {
            "$ref": "./resources/codes.json"
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "parameters": {
            "$ref": "./parameters/_index.json"
        },
        "schemas": {
            "$ref": "./schemas/_index.json"
        },
        "responses": {
            "$ref": "./responses/_index.json"
        }
    }
}
```

The `schemas/_index.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "Name": {
        "$ref": "./Name.json"
    },
    "Code": {
        "$ref": "./Code.json"
    }
}
```

Code.json looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "names": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "./Name.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Name.json like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "code": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` does not generate the Name object, and Code will contain an array of `Object` instead.

Also, my plugin configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
                            <inputSpec>${openapi.input.file}</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.pack.example.controller</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.pack.example.dto</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your plugin configuration ?

Comment: I have added it right now. The `openapi.input.file` is openapi.json